# MYSQL export data with their column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I import data in excel from mysql and i want get the names of columns.

I do this final command for import the data and i just want have the headers of each columns and of the two tables of the join

```
SELECT * FROM direction_prix_proxi.matrice_sigma ref LEFT JOIN direction_prix_proxi.volumestest using(SIGMA)
```

I know the command

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM
```

But i dont know if i can use it for that

Thanks !!

ps: i'm a beginner lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the headers of multiple tables (i.e. through a join), then you cannot use

```sql
SHOW COLUMNS FROM ...
```

Instead, try using:

```sql
SELECT column_name -- or use CONCAT_WS('.', table_name, column_name)
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name IN ('matrice_sigma', 'volumetest');
```